# Visual studio code (vscode) - Angular - Cannot open file from problems (clicking on problem link redirects to wrong path)

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

**Coding Context:**

- Angular : v15 (and same error on 13)
- NodeJS : v18.10 (and tried with v16.18 also)
- NPM : v8.10.0
- VsCode : 1.73.1

**Problem:**

When there is a syntax error in my Angular/TypeScript code, VisualCode will show my error in the 'Problem' tab, but if I click the error, there is an ERROR.

The error is : "The editor could not be opened because the file was not found".

[image: Error: The editor could not be opened because the file was not found]

Investigation (in case it helps) :  When I look closer, the link that visual Studio tries to open is WRONG :

> Instead of opening the file
> C:\Users\simon\sandbox\learnRxJS2\src\app\app.component.ts
>
> It is trying to open :
> C:\Users\simon\sandbox\learnRxJS2\Error: src\app\app.component.ts

there is an 'Error: ' inserted between the "workspace" and the "relative path".

**Details of the 3 scenarios:**

***A - Editor Opened, before initial RUN***
Before opening the file containing my error, NO ERROR (No 'problems') shown.

When I manually open the editor [clicking on the file in File Explorer]  :
[image: the error is shown correctly]

If i CLOSE the Editor windows, the error will DISAPPEAR from the Problem Tab.  That's ok, and maybe that's a clue..

***B - Editor Closed, After trying to RUN the project***
If i CLOSE the app.component.ts file from the editor,  No more 'Problems' reported in my Code.

Then I simply RUN Angular (f5) => it will fails and show my error in the PROBLEM tabs.

That's where i CANNOT click in the link :
[image: Visual Studio code shows the error]

***C - Editor opened AND after trying to RUN the project***

Finally, If i OPEN my error file by Hand (with File explorer),  the error will be shown 2 times!! If I click on the 'new' problem,  the editor will FIND the line of code.
If I click on the Other one, the error 'Cnanot fin file' will show up again!
[image]

Here is a Guy facing the SAME problem, but with VSCODE + SalesForce : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/377152/problems-are-returning-errors-linking-to-incorrect-file-locations-giving-the-e

Comment: how exactly do you run the project?

Answer (score 1):

The standard [predefined $tsc pattern](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/a3a7f52f7ce697b3e6167cbdc47741d80f7b0867/extensions/typescript-language-features/package.json#L1387) can't match `ng build` output command (they changed that output at some point).

It looks like:

```
{
  "name": "tsc",
  "regexp": "^([^\\s].*)[\\(:](\\d+)[,:](\\d+)(?:\\):\\s+|\\s+-\\s+)(error|warning|info)\\s+TS(\\d+)\\s*:\\s*(.*)$",
  "file": 1,
  "line": 2,
  "column": 3,
  "severity": 4,
  "code": 5,
  "message": 6
}
```

[image]

As you can see, it's just a regexp. That's why it takes `Error: src/app/app.component.ts` as a file path.

---

To workaround it, you could optionally prefix the word `Error` to it.

So, go to **.vscode/tasks.json** and replace all `"pattern": "$tsc",` places with:

```
"pattern": {
  "regexp": "^(Error: )?([^\\s].*)[\\(:](\\d+)[,:](\\d+)(?:\\):\\s+|\\s+-\\s+)(error|warning|info)\\s+TS(\\d+)\\s*:\\s*(.*)$",
  "file": 2,
  "line": 3,
  "column": 4,
  "severity": 5,
  "code": 6,
  "message": 7
},
```

[image]

There is similar reported issue in github https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/625#issuecomment-801327945

See also:

- [Problem Matcher for Angular CLI Build/Serve/Test Commands in VS Code](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/vs-code-task-problem-matcher-for-angular-cli-build-serve-test-commands)